# Labeling vertices of a polygon in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Given a set of points in the plane `T={a1,a2,...,an}` then `Graphics[Polygon[T]]` will plot the polygon generated by the points. How can I add labels to the polygon's vertices? Have merely the index as a label would be better then nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
Graphics[
 {{LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  {pts /. {x_, y_} :> Text[Style[{x, y}, Red], {x, y}]}}
 ]
```

[image]

To add point also

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
Graphics[
 {{LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  {pts /. {x_, y_} :> Text[Style[{x, y}, Red], {x, y}, {0, -1}]},
  {pts /. {x_, y_} :> {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, y}]}}
  }
 ]
```

[image]

**update:**

Use the index:

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
Graphics[
 {{LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  {pts /. {x_, y_} :> 
     Text[Style[Position[pts, {x, y}], Red], {x, y}, {0, -1}]}
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice. Almost what I'm after. How can alter your example, and obtain the index of the vertex as a label rather then the coordinates? Thanks in advance!

Comment: WOW! That's really great! Can you add some explanation what's the magic?

Comment: How can we get rid of the curly brackets wrapping the labels?

Answer (score 8):

[Nasser's version (update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922891/labeling-vertices-of-a-polygon-in-mathematica/6923030#6923030) uses [pattern matching](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html). This one uses [functional programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html). `MapIndexed` gives you both the coordinates and their index without the need for `Position` to find it.

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
Graphics[
 {
  {LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], Red], #1, {0, -1}] &, pts]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

or, if you don't like `MapIndexed`, here's a version with `Apply` (at level 1, infix notation `@@@`).

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
idx = Range[Length[pts]];
Graphics[
 {
  {LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  Text[Style[#2, Red], #1, {0, -1}] & @@@ ({pts, idx}\[Transpose])
  }
 ]
```

This can be expanded to arbitrary labels as follows:

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}};
idx = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
Graphics[
 {
  {LightGray, Polygon[pts]},
  Text[Style[#2, Red], #1, {0, -1}] & @@@ ({pts, idx}\[Transpose])
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the options of `GraphPlot` for this.  Example:

```
c = RandomReal[1, {3, 2}]
g = GraphPlot[c, VertexLabeling -> True, VertexCoordinateRules -> c];

Graphics[{Polygon@c, g[[1]]}]
```

This way you can also make use of `VertexLabeling -> Tooltip`, or `VertexRenderingFunction` if you want to.  If you do not want the edges overlaid, you may add `EdgeRenderingFunction -> None` to the `GraphPlot` function.  Example:

```
c = RandomReal[1, {3, 2}]
g = GraphPlot[c, VertexLabeling -> All, VertexCoordinateRules -> c, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> None, 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .02], 
       Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)];

Graphics[{Brown, Polygon@c, g[[1]]}]
```

[image]